# Solve for $x$ in $x\cdot 2^x -8x = 0$

Tags: calculus

$x\cdot 2^x -8x = 0$

I tried:

$$x\cdot 2^x -8x = 0 \Leftrightarrow x\cdot 2^x = 8x \Leftrightarrow 2^x = 8 \Leftrightarrow x = 3$$

But my book says the solution is $x = 0 \lor x = 3$

How do I get the right solution? What did I do wrong?

Comment: factor it to $x(2^x - 8)=0$ so either $x=0$ or $2^x-8=0$. $2^x$ is injective so solutions are $0$ and $3$. In your solution note that $x=0$ then dividing by $x$ is not allowed

Comment: Factor out by $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What assumption do you have to make to divide by $x$ as you did? Did you perhaps miss a solution?

Comment: I made that assumption because $x\cdot 2^x = 8x \Leftrightarrow 2^x =\frac{ 8\cdot x}{x}  \Leftrightarrow x \cdot 2^x = 8$. I assumed that multiplying by $x$ and dividing by $x$ cancelled each other out. Is this incorrect?

Comment: it is only correct if $x$ is nonzero, since $0/0$ is meaningless.

Comment: Right, I understand

Answer (score 1):

$$2^x = 8x \Leftrightarrow 2^x = 8 \,\,\ \text{holds iff} \,\,\, x \not = 0$$ So $x=0$ is a possible solution, apart from $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are dividing by zero, because x can be zero. Therefore, what you can do is factor out the x to get:

$x(2^x - 8) = 0$

Therefore, either x must equal 0 or $2^x - 8$ must equal 0.

From there, it's pretty simple.